# Android: TextView Locked for update

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

I have a thread that **start** playing mp3 file, in this thread i update my `TextView` after round trip i use other thred to update my player and my `TextView` but in this case the textview not updated ?!

```
public void updatePlayProgressUpdater() {
            SharedPreferences  sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            mediaLengthInSeconds = sharedPreferences.getLong("mediaLengthInSeconds", 0);            
            float mediaPositionSeconds = sharedPreferences.getFloat("mediaPositionSeconds", 0);
            float progress = (mediaPositionSeconds / mediaLengthInSeconds);
            sb.setProgress((int) (progress * 100));

            sb.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    seekChange(v);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            try {
                textStreamed
                .setText(convertDuration(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000)
                        + "/" + convertDuration(mediaLengthInSeconds)); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("Exception","");
            }

                Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        updatePlayProgressUpdater();
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
            }
```

...

```
Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startPlayProgressUpdater();
                    }
                };
```

...

```
// comment ...


   public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {

            mediaLengthInSeconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000;
            float mediaPositionSeconds = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
            float progress = (mediaPositionSeconds / mediaLengthInSeconds);

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putLong("mediaLengthInSeconds", mediaLengthInSeconds);
            editor.putFloat("mediaPositionSeconds", mediaPositionSeconds);
            editor.commit();   // I missed to save the data to preference here,.

            sb.setProgress((int) (progress * 100));     
//          playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            sb.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    seekChange(v);
                    return false;
                }
            });
            textStreamed
                    .setText(convertDuration(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000)
                            + "/" + convertDuration(mediaLengthInSeconds));
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        startPlayProgressUpdater();
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
            }
        }
```

...

```
private void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences  sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int  state = sharedPreferences.getInt("stateDB", 0);        
        sb.setProgress(state);
        textStreamed.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("statetextStreamed", ""));
        coursTitle.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("coursTitle", ""));
        coursIntervenant.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("coursIntervenant", ""));
        new Thread() {
              public void run() {

                      try {
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                              @Override
                              public void run() {
                                  updatePlayProgressUpdater();
                              }
                          });
                          Thread.sleep(300);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      }
              }
          }.start();

       }
```

...

```
@Override
       protected void onResume() {      
           super.onResume();
           LoadPreferences();           
       }
```

Comment: please post the code that you have tried, so everyone can take a look at it and help you.

Comment: Does the try code fire the catch statement ?

Comment: No exception triggered

Comment: where is updatePlayProgressUpdater function calling ? and also check for the convertDuration(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000)
                            + "/" + convertDuration(mediaLengthInSeconds) method.

Comment: @Krish yes i have checked the 'mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000) + "/" + convertDuration(mediaLengthInSeconds)' .. its value is set

Comment: updatePlayProgressUpdater this function calling in mainThread right?

Comment: @Krish yes .. but in separate thread

Comment: can you print log on these methods like updatePlayProgressUpdater & startPlayProgressUpdater

Comment: i have checked all parts there no exception

Comment: can you post whole code .Then may be I can check it.

Answer (score 0):

on [line 525](https://github.com/selmanon/AudioFileActivity/blob/master/AudioFilesActivity.java#L525) replace `startPlayProgressUpdater();` with:

```
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    startPlayProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification, 1000);
```

Comment: clan you explain me why the seekbar are updated and textview not at all

Answer (score 0):

When you create an app, there is a single main thread (referred to as the UI thread) that handles all UI updating.  Other threads you create cannot update the UI directly.  It sounds like you have two update methods, one being called from the UI thread and one from a background thread.

There are many articles that explain it better than I can, such as http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html.

Comment: But in the same code i update my seekbar (updated seccessflly)

Comment: If you think the code works because you've used it before, then maybe your code isn't being called like you expect.  Have you debugged or added print statements?

Comment: i have debug it step by step

Comment: How about if you replace whatever you're putting into the textview with something much simpler?  Maybe there's a problem with retrieving values from the PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).  Also, I see 3 different textviews in your code, are you setting all the ones you want to?

Comment: @Grep i have published the complete code https://github.com/selmanon/AudioFileActivity/blob/master/AudioFilesActivity.java

Comment: It looks like in #updatePlayProgressUpdater(), you never commit anything to the SharedPreferences, so you're working with the same data each time through the method.